# Using libasla-intf on Android

Tags: android, makefile, android-source, alsa

How can I call functions from `libalsa-intf` on AOSP? Adding `libalsa-intf` in `Android.mk` to section `LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES` has no effect.

`make` fails with:

`` make: *** No rule to make target `out/target/product/generic/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libalsa-intf_intermediates/export_includes', needed by `out/target/product/generic/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/my_project/import_includes'. ``

Comment: I believe `libalsa-intf` is specific for Quallcom chips.

Comment: Any ideas how to diagnose this problem?

Comment: Is your build target based on Quallcom, or not?

Comment: Yes, it is. My hardware has qcom components.

Comment: One peculiar note, you need `BOARD_USES_ALSA_AUDIO=true` in your build environment.